# SERVICE_STARTUP_FAILED error occurs randomly in a docker compose environment

Tags: docker, selenoid

I'm running tests on a set of jenkins nodes with selenoid in a docker compose and I'm finding that sometimes the tests are failing randomly because selenium does not respond, normally it takes just a few seconds. Looking at the node it seems that it has enough memory and cpu, any idea what could be happening here?

````
2021/07/28 15:19:48 [-] [NEW_REQUEST_ACCEPTED] [unknown] [192.168.240.4]
2021/07/28 15:19:48 [3] [LOCATING_SERVICE] [firefox] []
2021/07/28 15:19:48 [-] [DEFAULT_VERSION] [Using default version: 72]
2021/07/28 15:19:48 [3] [USING_DOCKER] [firefox] [72]
2021/07/28 15:19:48 [3] [CREATING_CONTAINER] [selenoid/firefox:72.0]
2021/07/28 15:19:48 [3] [STARTING_CONTAINER] [selenoid/firefox:72.0] [743731426c4ae30549f824c5a4a7a7aae9a48367e1b1612b1d9f48b7cd2baee4]
2021/07/28 15:19:49 [3] [CONTAINER_STARTED] [selenoid/firefox:72.0] [743731426c4ae30549f824c5a4a7a7aae9a48367e1b1612b1d9f48b7cd2baee4] [0.46s]
2021/07/28 15:20:49 [3] [REMOVING_CONTAINER] [743731426c4ae30549f824c5a4a7a7aae9a48367e1b1612b1d9f48b7cd2baee4]
2021/07/28 15:20:49 [3] [CONTAINER_REMOVED] [743731426c4ae30549f824c5a4a7a7aae9a48367e1b1612b1d9f48b7cd2baee4]
2021/07/28 15:20:49 [3] [SERVICE_STARTUP_FAILED] [wait: http://172.17.0.3:4444/wd/hub does not respond in 1m0s]```
````

Answer (score 0):

Could be for example because of slow \ overloaded disk or wrong capabilities set. Need to take a look at system metrics like CPU load, load average, memory usage, iowait and so on. Also I would take a look at browser container log (you can do this during this minute with regular `docker logs` command).

Comment: it seems this problem is solved now, there were many browser containers running in the machine, so it could be affecting the performance.

Answer (score 0):

So this issue seems to be solved, we added a scripts that cleans any browser container left in the machine after the executions, however i'm facing another issue now:

```
2021/08/04 03:16:06 [-] [NEW_REQUEST] [unknown] [172.17.0.6]
2021/08/04 03:16:06 [-] [NEW_REQUEST_ACCEPTED] [unknown] [172.17.0.6]
2021/08/04 03:16:06 [175] [LOCATING_SERVICE] [firefox] []
2021/08/04 03:16:06 [-] [DEFAULT_VERSION] [Using default version: 72]
2021/08/04 03:16:06 [175] [USING_DOCKER] [firefox] [72]
2021/08/04 03:16:06 [175] [CREATING_CONTAINER] [selenoid/firefox:72.0]
2021/08/04 03:16:09 [175] [STARTING_CONTAINER] [selenoid/firefox:72.0] [b03f86e30e850bb48ce1194bc49b3549e369cb1511754aa1c24c29483a538fa9]
2021/08/04 03:16:10 [175] [CONTAINER_STARTED] [selenoid/firefox:72.0] [b03f86e30e850bb48ce1194bc49b3549e369cb1511754aa1c24c29483a538fa9] [1.37s]
[2021-08-04 04:16:26.385047] Exception trying to get the WebDriver instance:
HTTPConnectionPool(host='172.17.0.2', port=4444): Read timed out. (read timeout=20)
2021/08/04 03:16:27 [175] [SERVICE_STARTED] [firefox:72.0] [b03f86e30e850bb48ce1194bc49b3549e369cb1511754aa1c24c29483a538fa9] [16.91s]
2021/08/04 03:16:27 [175] [PROXY_TO] [b03f86e30e850bb48ce1194bc49b3549e369cb1511754aa1c24c29483a538fa9] [http://172.17.0.16:4444/wd/hub]
2021/08/04 03:16:27 [175] [SESSION_ATTEMPTED] [http://172.17.0.16:4444/wd/hub] [1]
2021/08/04 03:16:27 [175] [CLIENT_DISCONNECTED] [unknown] [172.17.0.6] [20.92s]
```

it seems the browser container takes to long to be up and the selenium request times out, is there a way to fix this?